# No Rule to make target C:/...../x86Debug/lib/liblibcurl_a_debug.a, needed by debug/AlgoApplicationUI.exe. Stop

Tags: c++, qt

I just recently installed libcurl library and i am newer to C++ and libraries in general and i used the library installation wizard through QT but now i keep getting this error, I will attach my AlgoApplicationUi.pro code which if im correct is basically the makefile, just easier to edit.

My include path to get the the folder that has curl.h is
C:\Users\laner\Documents\GitHub\AlgoApp\Program\Libraries\curl-7.69.1\x86Debug_include\curl

My .lib file path is
C:\Users\laner\Documents\GitHub\AlgoApp\Program\Libraries\curl-7.69.1\x86Debug\lib\libcurl_a_debug

```
QT      += core gui
QT      += core gui charts
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++11

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any Qt feature that has been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
TEMPLATE = app
RC_FILE = myapp.rc.txt

# You can also make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    MainWindow.cpp \
    login.cpp \
    main.cpp \
    webscrapper.cpp

HEADERS += \
    MainWindow.h \
    login.h \
    webscrapper.h

FORMS += \
    MainWindow.ui \
    login.ui \


DISTFILES += \
    Contents/banner.qml

RESOURCES += \
    res.qrc



unix|win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../Libraries/curl-7.69.1/x86Debug/lib/ -llibcurl_a_debug

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../Libraries/curl-7.69.1/x86Debug/_include/curl
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../Libraries/curl-7.69.1/x86Debug/_include/curl

win32:!win32-g++: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../Libraries/curl-7.69.1/x86Debug/lib/libcurl_a_debug.lib
else:unix|win32-g++: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../Libraries/curl-7.69.1/x86Debug/lib/liblibcurl_a_debug.a
```

Comment: Does the listed file exist? If not why not?

Comment: Well I am kind of confused because it is looking for a .exe but isnt the .exe created when the compiler goes off?

Comment: It's looking for the dependent static library: `C:/...../x86Debug/lib/liblibcurl_a_debug.a` that it can't find and since you listed this as a dependency with `PRE_TARGETDEPS` I believe it tries to look for a rule to build it which it did not have because your .pro file does not build the curl library.

Comment: So to fix this do i just do: LIBS += C:/Users/laner/Documents/GitHub/AlgoApp/Program/Libraries/curl-7.69.1/x86Release/lib -llibcurl_a.lib
INCLUDEPATH += C:/Users/laner/Documents/GitHub/AlgoApp/Program/Libraries/curl-7.69.1/x86Release/_include/curl